# expressions doesn't return float value

Tags: c++

when i try to calculate any expression, I always get an integer result, it's like:

```
float k= 5/12;
std::cout<< k<<std::endl;
```

the output in the console is always 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C/C++, this is an integer division:

```
5/12
```

What you want is a floating point division:

```
5.0/12.0
```

Please note that this has absolutely *nothing* to do with GLUT or OpenGL.

Comment: `5.0/12.0` is actually a `double` division. If you want to operate on values of type `float`, it would be `5.0f/12.0f`.